# mysql left join statement running slow

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, left-join

Having an issue with with a very slow mysql query using left joins.

```
SELECT ip,T1.ipaddr,host,referrer,agent,page,url,thedate,DV,PV,notes
FROM visits_temp AS T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ipaddr,COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(thedate,10)) AS DV
    FROM visits GROUP BY ipaddr
) AS T2 ON T1.ipaddr = T2.ipaddr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ipaddr,notes
    FROM topvisitors
) As T3 ON T3.ipaddr = T1.ipaddr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ipaddr,COUNT(ip) AS PV
    FROM visits
    GROUP BY ipaddr
) AS T4 ON T4.ipaddr = T1.ipaddr
WHERE referrer = '' AND
    thedate BETWEEN '2013-01-07 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-09 23:59:59'
GROUP BY T1.ip
ORDER BY thedate desc
```

The goal here is to get all the direct visitors traffic for the website than the LEFT JOINS do a find to give the total number of Days Visited (DV) and the total number of Pages Viewed (PV). The visits table has about 2.9m records currently and the ipaddr and thedate field ARE indexed. This query takes close to 90 secs to complete.

```
SELECT ipaddr,COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(thedate,10)) AS DV FROM visits GROUP BY ipaddr
```

or

```
SELECT ipaddr,COUNT(ip) AS PV FROM visits GROUP BY ipaddr
```

The individual select statements in the LEFT JOINS when ran by themselves will complete in 0.03 seconds. Maybe LEFT JOIN isn't the right way to go in this situation I'd be open to alternatives.

Comment: Have you tried `EXPLAIN PLAN`? What does it show?

Comment: I've had large tables perform VERY badly when using `between` on date ranges. somehow mysql refuses to indexes when such a construct is used.

Comment: @MarcB Does using `Date >= LowerBownd and Date <=UpperBound` fix the problem?

Comment: nope. `x between y and z` is the same as `x >=y and x<=z` anyways as far as the compiler/parser is concerned. never could figure out a workaround, and in the end just punted and partitioned the table.

Comment: What are the data types of the ipaddr and thedate fields?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

You are using referrer and thedate in your where clause.  Creating a compound index on those two fields in the visits_temp table may improve performance.

Make sure you have an index on the ipaddr field in the topvisitors table also.

Answer (score 0):

Those 4 subqueries are probably slowing things down a bit.

This should be identical to your query, just faster:

```
SELECT ip,T1.ipaddr,host,referrer,agent,page,url,thedate,DV,PV,notes
FROM visits_temp AS T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ipaddr, COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(thedate,10)) AS DV, COUNT(ip) AS PV
    FROM visits
    GROUP BY ipaddr
) AS T2 ON T1.ipaddr = T2.ipaddr
LEFT JOIN topvisitors T3 ON T3.ipaddr = T1.ipaddr
WHERE referrer = '' AND
    thedate BETWEEN '2013-01-07 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-09 23:59:59'
GROUP BY T1.ip
ORDER BY thedate desc
```

If every row of `T1` is guaranteed to have a matching row in `T2` and `T3`, you can replace your `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN`, this should allow the optimiser to do more, which can also speed things up (though there are exceptions).

I can't imagine that this returns the desired results, it will group on `ipaddr`, but then only return (any) 1 of these groupings for each `ip`. MySQL doesn't prevent this. If you elaborate a bit on your requirements (in terms of the fields / tables you use), it shouldn't be too difficult to fix this (though this probably technically belongs in a different question).